# Proof of Max-Min Inequality

Tags: optimization, solution-verification, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, maxima-minima

Is this a correct proof of the Max-Min Inequality? And if not how could it be improved? Thank you for your help.

Given $g\colon X\times Y\to \mathbb{R}$, we note that for any $\tilde{x} \in X$, $\tilde{y}\in Y$ that

$$\inf_{x\in X}g(x,\tilde{y}) \leq g(\tilde{x},\tilde{y}) \leq \sup_{y\in Y}g(\tilde{x},y)$$
so for arbitrary $x\in X$, $y\in Y$
$$\inf_{x\in X}g(x,y) \leq \sup_{y\in Y}g(x,y)$$

Taking the supremum over all $y\in Y$ leaves the right-hand side unaffected so
$$\sup_{y\in Y}\left(\inf_{x\in X}g(x,y)\right)\leq \sup_{y\in Y}g(x,y)$$
Finally take the infimum over all $x\in X$ yields the desired result
$$\sup_{y\in Y}\left(\inf_{x\in X}g(x,y)\right)\leq \inf_{x\in X}\left(\sup_{y\in Y}g(x,y)\right)$$

Comment: That's the general idea, but you should replace some $x,y$ in the proof by $\tilde{x},\tilde{y}$ to distinguish the two.

Comment: As in instead of "arbitrary $x, y$" it should be "arbitrary $\tilde{x}, \tilde{y}$" and then use that notation in the supremum and infimum that follow? Thank you this is helpful feedback.

Comment: Yes. (15 characters)